# How to Hide 3D viewport

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to remove drawing the scene twice but keep a U.I window open ?
I have a second window, but I want it 100% just for that  Rigify fast select options.

My question, how do I disable the 3D engine (or close to that) on the 2nd window I really just want to display the U.I

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but at the top left of the viewport(s) is a button that looks like a grid with a sphere above it - this lets you change the editor type. Click change it from a 3D viewport  to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Each viewport's display options are independant from each other, so you can use that at your advantage.

First, let's hide every object type we have in a viewport using the View Object Types popover:

[image: view object types popover]

Open this popover, and <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>-drag down the entire eye icons' column to disable this viewport's object types display.

Now you still have the rig and gizmo displayed. But then to make it better : you can simply disable the viewport's overlays and gizmo by toggling off these buttons:

[image: disable overlays and gizmo]

Demo:

[image: demo popover]

Comment: Legend! I remember this now xD forgot about this!

Comment: Glad it helps! Don't forget to accept this post as answer with the checkmark button bellow the votes buttons.